# Highcharts : single call to Google sheets to generate multiple charts

Tags: google-sheets, highcharts

I'm developing a web page with multiple charts using Highcharts. Every chart is using a different worksheet as a feed for its data.

Is there an easy way to make only one call to Google sheets to get the whole sheet in one call and then use the response to feed every single chart?

Here is a sample [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gaxbmhqv/)

```
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {

title: {
    text: 'Highcharts data from Google Spreadsheets'
},

data: {
    googleSpreadsheetKey: '1D0v11GK07TJu6fXcwbcofiPOo4FmRpATGBAaSBqNlZE',
    googleSpreadsheetWorksheet: 1
}

});

// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container2', {

title: {
    text: 'Second chart'
},

data: {
    googleSpreadsheetKey: '1D0v11GK07TJu6fXcwbcofiPOo4FmRpATGBAaSBqNlZE',
    googleSpreadsheetWorksheet: 2
}

});
```

Comment: Hi @The Jakester, Unfortunately Highcharts does not have that functionality. You would have to get all data in some way and manually split it into the required series structure.